# X11 files not found on macOS Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I try to compile a library on macOS with Xcode. But the compile always told me that it cannot find the x11 header files. I have installed the x11 libraries. 
After reading some threads here on this website I also checked my files. I was able to find X11 header files at: /opt/X11/include/X11
And I also made a symbolic link to /usr/local/include/

sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11

But still the compiler said that the X11 header files are not there. 
I expected /usr/local/include/ as a common system search path for include files.

Anything I missed todo?

Comment: Just add the path to the compiler flags?

Comment: How to do this? I configured with CMAKE. Where I have to do this?

Comment: I add the path to X1 in XCOde Header search path. No success, too.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] with the exact error message